# Spring Boot: OpenApi Generator Plugin creates unwanted test file

Tags: spring-boot, maven, openapi, openapi-generator

I use OpenApi 3.0 and the maven plugin *openapi-generator-maven-plugin* to generate my api + objects.

This is my maven config:

```
                    <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/BookingService.yaml</inputSpec>
                        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                        <modelPackage>${clientPackage}.model</modelPackage>
                        <invokerPackage>${clientPackage}.invoker</invokerPackage>
                        <apiPackage>${clientPackage}.api</apiPackage>
                        <generateApis>true</generateApis>
                        <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                        <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                        <configOptions>
                            <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```

It works as expected, however its also generating tests that I do not want. As you can see in my config i disabled the tests for Api tests + Model tests..

[image]

The compilation of these tests fail bc it "Cannot resolve symbol 'SpringBootTest'" in the build target folder...

These tests do not have any sense, how can I disable them?

Comment: Without changing the code I have not found a way to do this without switching to interface only generation which I do not want. I have a workaround in my IDE to set the generated test folder to "Excluded" which makes it work but I also would like to just have the option not to generate the test case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note this is a workaround. It would be better to get a property to not generate this testcase, but for now this seems to work...

Add this maven plugin to your pom.xml

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <!-- remove the unwanted generated testcases by the spring generator of openapi -->
                    <delete dir="${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/openapi/src/test" />
                </target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

It will delete that entire test package after the sources have been generated in the process-sources phase

Answer (score 0):

We can skip the generation by enabling `<interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>` but `delegatePattern` will not consider.

Here is the source code from openapi-generator...
[Source Code](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/0a69f11526f68753e958254c80c8ef89b69ef699/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/java/org/openapitools/codegen/languages/SpringCodegen.java#L469)

```
if (!interfaceOnly) {
        if (SPRING_BOOT.equals(library)) {
            if (useSwaggerUI && selectedDocumentationProviderRequiresSwaggerUiBootstrap()) {
                supportingFiles.add(new SupportingFile("swagger-ui.mustache", "src/main/resources/static", "swagger-ui.html"));
            }
            // rename template to SpringBootApplication.mustache
            supportingFiles.add(new SupportingFile("openapi2SpringBoot.mustache",
                    (sourceFolder + File.separator + basePackage).replace(".", java.io.File.separator),
                    "OpenApiGeneratorApplication.java"));
            supportingFiles.add(new SupportingFile("SpringBootTest.mustache",
                (testFolder + File.separator + basePackage).replace(".", java.io.File.separator),
                "OpenApiGeneratorApplicationTests.java"));
            supportingFiles.add(new SupportingFile("RFC3339DateFormat.mustache",
                    (sourceFolder + File.separator + basePackage).replace(".", java.io.File.separator),
                    "RFC3339DateFormat.java"));
        }
....
```

You can always exclude the generated test package in Intellij IDE for local compilation issue.

Answer (score 0):

An detailed response can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76369775/7213979).

But, briefly example is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.kinlhp</groupId>
    <artifactId>moname-build</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <description>Project to money me with no name [build].</description>
    <url>https://moname.kinlhp.com</url>
    <properties>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}</main.basedir>
        <maven.compiler.release>${java.version}</maven.compiler.release>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <openapi-generator.base-package>com.kinlhp.moname.commons.api.oas</openapi-generator.base-package>
        <openapi-generator.input-spec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi/specification.yaml</openapi-generator.input-spec>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <!-- dependency versions -->
        <revision>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</revision>
        <!-- # third party # -->
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <openapi-generator-maven-plugin.version>6.6.0</openapi-generator-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!-- # third party # -->
                <!-- openapitools -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${openapi-generator-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>openapi-generator</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <!-- README#openapi-generator-spring-metadata -->
                                <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                                <!-- README#openapi-generator-spring-config-options -->
                                <apiPackage>${openapi-generator.base-package}.endpoint</apiPackage>
                                <artifactId>moname-commons-api-oas</artifactId>
                                <artifactVersion>${revision}</artifactVersion>
                                <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                                <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                <ignoreFileOverride>.openapi-generator-ignore</ignoreFileOverride>
                                <inputSpec>${openapi-generator.input-spec}</inputSpec>
                                <invokerPackage>${openapi-generator.base-package}.invoker</invokerPackage>
                                <modelNameSuffix>DTO</modelNameSuffix>
                                <modelPackage>${openapi-generator.base-package}.payload</modelPackage>
                                <configOptions>
                                    <!-- README#openapi-generator-spring-metadata -->
                                    <generatorLanguage>Java</generatorLanguage>
                                    <generatorType>SERVER</generatorType>
                                    <!-- README#openapi-generator-spring-config-options -->
                                    <artifactDescription>Project to money me with no name [commons-api-oas].</artifactDescription>
                                    <artifactUrl>${project.url}</artifactUrl>
                                    <basePackage>${openapi-generator.base-package}</basePackage>
                                    <bigDecimalAsString>true</bigDecimalAsString>
                                    <booleanGetterPrefix>is</booleanGetterPrefix>
                                    <configPackage>${openapi-generator.base-package}.configuration</configPackage>
                                    <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                                    <developerEmail>lhp.kin@gmail.com</developerEmail>
                                    <developerName>Luis Henrique Pereira</developerName>
                                    <developerOrganization>${project.organization.name}</developerOrganization>
                                    <developerOrganizationUrl>${project.organization.url}</developerOrganizationUrl>
                                    <licenseName>MIT License</licenseName>
                                    <licenseUrl>https://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php</licenseUrl>
                                    <parentArtifactId>moname-commons</parentArtifactId>
                                    <parentGroupId>${project.parent.groupId}</parentGroupId>
                                    <parentVersion>${revision}</parentVersion>
                                    <performBeanValidation>true</performBeanValidation>
                                    <scmConnection>${project.scm.connection}</scmConnection>
                                    <scmDeveloperConnection>${project.scm.developerConnection}</scmDeveloperConnection>
                                    <scmUrl>${project.scm.url}</scmUrl>
                                    <serializableModel>true</serializableModel>
                                    <title>Project to money me with no name [commons-api-oas].</title>
                                    <unhandledException>true</unhandledException>
                                    <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>
                                    <useSpringController>true</useSpringController>
                                </configOptions>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```